# Вывести пользователю в чате Telegtam клавиатуру без отправки сообщения

Tags: telegram-bot

Нормально клавиатура отправляется пользователю как параметр функций sendXXX, в нагрузку к обязательному контенту сообщения. Возможно ли отобразить у пользователя клавиатуру без сообщения?

Comment: Нет. Это атрибут сообщения.

Comment: В отношении инлайн-клавиатур - да. ReplyKeyboardMarkup - очень спорно. Она работает вне контекста сообщения.